# Independent identically distributed random variables, almost surely

Tags: probability

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, ...$  be independent identically distributed random variables.
Prove that $\displaystyle\sup_{n} \xi_n=\infty$ almost surely if and only if$P(\xi_1>A)>0$  for every $A$.

Any idea how to start, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can start by writing
$$ \{\sup_{n}\xi_n<\infty\}=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\xi_n\leq m\} $$

Note that
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcap_{n=1}^N\{\xi_n\leq m\}\Big)=\mathbb{P}(\xi_1\leq m)^N $$
since the $\xi_n$ are i.i.d.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the suggestion...

Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sup_{n} \{\xi_n < \infty \} &\geq& \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{\xi_n < \infty \}\\
&=& \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \ \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} \{\xi_m  < \infty\}\right)\\
P \left(\sup_{n} \{\xi_n < \infty\}\right)&=&P\left[ \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \ \left( \ \bigcap_{k=n}^{N} \{\xi_m  < \infty\}\right)\right]\\
&=& \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ P\left( \ \bigcap_{k=n}^{N} \{\xi_m \leq \infty\}\right)\right] \\
&=& \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \ \displaystyle\prod_{k=n}^{N} P\{\xi_n  < \infty\}\right)\\
&=& \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[P(\xi_1< \infty)^{n-N} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}  something like that? and now?